# Connection between forms for Generalized Pareto Distribution

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, extreme-value, pareto-distribution

On Wikipedia ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Pareto_types_I–IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Pareto_types_I%E2%80%93IV)) one can find the relation between the different types of Pareto Distribution and the Generalized Pareto Distribution (Type IV). A more appropriate explanation on the relation between types of the distribution can be found in the book:

https://www.amazon.it/Distributions-Chapman-Monographs-Statistics-Probability-ebook/dp/B00UVB2PWY

The relationship is summarized as follows:

[image]

On the "Generalized Pareto Distribution" Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution) one can find a different formulation for the same distribution, in particular the  survival function here is defined as:

$$
\overline{F}(x) = \left( 1 + \xi/\sigma \cdot ( x - \mu) \right)^{-1/\xi}
$$

what is the connection between this survival function and:

$$
\overline{F}(x) = \left[ 1 + \left( 1/\sigma \cdot ( x - \mu) \right) ^{1/\gamma} \right]^{-\alpha} \text{?}
$$

Comment: The two families differ if and only if $\gamma\ne1$

Comment: There also is a $\xi$ in the first equation that is missing in the second even if $\gamma\neq 1$

Comment: No because the $\xi$ can be incorporated inside the $\sigma$, so this is not a genuine difference.

Comment: Ok so if I estimate the first, then I can also reasonably calculate the parameters of the second, assuming that $\gamma = 1$?

Comment: If you estimate $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ for the second model, the reparameterisation is $\xi=1/\alpha$ and $\sigma'=\alpha\sigma$ when $\gamma=1$.